# how to get data from other table that is not directly related in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I'm quite new to Laravel so I don't quite understand the eloquent and it's query syntaxes.

I want to get the `name` field in table `products` from `ProposalController`, but the table relationships are like this:

I read that I can use `whereHas` if there's a relationship between the wanted table. but can it be used for this case?

```
tb_proposal
-----------
id // primary key
customer_name
grand_total

tb_detail_proposal
------------------
id // primary key
proposal_id // foreign key to tb_proposal.id
product_id // foreign key to tb_product.id
qty
price

tb_product
----------
id // primary key
product_name
stock
price
```

this is what I have now in ProposalController.php:

```
class ProposalController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Proposal::latest();
        if (request('search')) {
            $data->where('customer_name', 'like', '%'.request('search').'%')
                ->orWhereHas('tb_product', function (Builder $query) {
                    $query->where('product_name', 'like', '%'.request('search').'%')
                });
        }

        $view_data = [
            'page_title' => 'Browse Proposals',
            'active' => 'proposal',
            'data' => $data->get()
        ];
        return view('proposal.index', $view_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have the relationship tb_product working ? tb_detail_proposal seems a pivot table so both the product and proposal model should have belongs to many relationship setup ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you instead move that logic into your model and keep your controller clean?

Here's what I would do:

Define the [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between `Product` and `Proposal`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Product extends Model
{
    // your code

    // define the relationship
    public function proposals(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Proposal::class, 'tb_detail_proposal')
            ->as('details');
    }
}
```

The details inside the relationship will give you the ability to get `qty` and `price`, see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#customizing-the-pivot-attribute-name).

Define the inverse relationship in Proposal:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Proposal extends Model
{
    // your code

    // define the relationship
    public function products(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'tb_detail_proposal')
            ->as('details');
    }
}
```

With these changes you can get either collection with the related models as such:

```
<?php

$proposal = Proposal::with('products')->latest();

$qty = $proposal->details->qty;
$price = $proposal->details->price;
$products = $proposal->products;
```

Now, how about the search term? You can create a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#query-scopes) (either a global or local scope, according to your needs). Here's the Proposal model, with an added search scope:

```
<?php

// previous imports
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Proposal extends Model
{
    // previous code

    public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, string $search): void
    {
        if (trim($search) == '') {
            return;
        }

        $query->where('customer_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhereHas('products', function (Builder $query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('product_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
            });
    }
}
```

To use this in your controller you simply call:

```
<?php

$search = request('search');
$proposal = Proposal::with('products')->search($search)->latest();
```

Comment: so I don't need a `tb_detail_proposal`? because that's how I've been taught all this time using mySQL..

Comment: you do! Laravel creates many-to-many-relationships with an intermediate table, in your case `tb_detail_proposal`. But this is not named via the expected Laravel naming conventions, therefore you should make some changes to the code:

`return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'tb_detail_proposal');` (code updated)

Answer (score 0):

No , because `whereHas` method in Laravel is specifically designed for querying based on relationships.

if you want to query the products table directly without a relationship, you would typically use a join (read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#joins)) or a separate query for the products table.

```php
// DRY: Don't repeat yourself
$searchTerm = request('search');

// Retrieve proposals with a join to related tables
$proposals = Proposal::join('tb_detail_proposal', 'tb_proposal.id', '=', 'tb_detail_proposal.proposal_id')
    ->join('tb_product', 'tb_detail_proposal.product_id', '=', 'tb_product.id')
    ->where('tb_product.product_name', 'like', '%' . $searchTerm . '%')
    ->select('tb_product.*')
    ->get();
```